# Run script while having browser focused

Tags: bash, shell, autostart

I am currently working on a home project with a Raspberry Pi and the 7" display. Almost everything works, only the last bit I am a bit confused with. A chromium window in kiosk mode is open which refreshes on mouse movement. Also on mouse movement I want to change the backlight for a few seconds to full light.

The script below works so far stand-alone:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
pos1=$(xdotool getmouselocation)
sleep 0.5
pos2=$(xdotool getmouselocation)

if [[ $pos1 != $pos2 ]]; then
        sudo /usr/local/bin/rpi-backlight -b 100
        sleep 10
        sudo /usr/local/bin/rpi-backlight -b 0 -d 2
fi

done
```

I already tried to make it happen by

1. putting it in one script together with the chromium call,
2. opening both in autostart,
3. creating a systemd service for the script above. It does not seem to work in the background.

Can anyone tell me, where I am mistaken?

Answer (score 0):

I made it happen by putting both in autostart. My syntax seemed to be wrong.

```
@/path/script.sh &
@chromium-browser --kiosk http://website.xyz
```

works like a charme, where ampersand "&" is for making it a background process.